# ServiceStack - RestService OPTION

Tags: servicestack

ServiceStack RestService has handlers for Get, Put,Post, Patch but not Option.
I would like to use "Option" to tell the client what operations are availabe given there authorization (role).

Is this posssible, bad practice, implemented already in ServiceStack, other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check [ServiceStack's New API](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/New-Api) for handling of OPTION requests, basically if you want to send back CORS headers on an Options request you can now do:

```
public class ReqstarsService : Service
{
    [EnableCors]
    public void Options(Reqstar request) {}
}
```